# 'TaskSerializer' object has no attribute 'start_date'

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hope You Are Good!

My question is how to get user input data in perform create method?

like in Django I use:

```
form.some_field
```

to get the field data but i can't do this in rest framework:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if serializer.start_date > date.today():
        serializer.status = "Schedule"
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I get this issue:

```
'TaskSerializer' object has no attribute 'start_date'
```

here is my model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    status_options = (("In Progress","In Progress",),("Cancelled","Cancelled",),("Completed","Completed",),("Schedule","Schedule",),)
    priority_options = (("Low","Low",),("Medium","Medium",),("High","High",),)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=124, choices=priority_options, default="Low")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=124, choices=status_options, default="In Progress")
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    altimedatetamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    recurring = models.BigIntegerField(default=0) 
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access `serializer.validated_data` to get your model field value.
And instead of manipulating the `status` value inside the serializer, consider passing it along the `save` method like you do with the user.

Your `perform_create` should look something like that:

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if serializer.validated_data['start_date'] > date.today():
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, status='Schedule')
    else:
      serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```